# React Metrics Graphics not showing when on render

Tags: reactjs, metricsgraphicsjs

I follow the installasion and usage of React Metrics Graphics on github [link](https://github.com/metricsgraphics/react-metrics-graphics) but not showing the graph when on render.

This is the link which i am trying to create [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8fpyoa?embed=1&file=index.js)

Anyone can helpme to show the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you've not given the props to the MetricGraphics Component inside the render method, but you have added it before the definition of class which does nothing, just remove it and paste it inside the render method, like below

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Hello name={this.state.name} />
    <p>
      Start editing to see some magic happen :)
    </p>
  <MetricsGraphics
    title="Downloads"
    description="This graphic shows a time-series of downloads."
    data={ [{'date':new Date('2014-11-01'),'value':12}, {'date':new Date('2014-11-02'),'value':18}] }
    width={600}
    height={250}
    x_accessor="date"
    y_accessor="value"
  />
  </div>
);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm sorry for my mistake.